# Good Alternatives for webmail when my server is down?

Tags: software-rec, webmail

My server went to maintainance today so i cant access my web mail..... Then looked around the web and found

[Mail2Web](http://mail2web.com/)

Looks quite interesting ... Anyother good ones which i can give a try....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure; checkout

- http://www.fusemail.com/
- http://www.e-mailanywhere.com/
- http://web2mail.com/lite/welcome.php